# How to build a simple sound-responsive LED in my subwoofer?

Tags: led, audio

I'm building my own subwoofer speaker box with LED rings that go around the subwoofer. The LED rings pulse with the bass, but I don't want the LEDs to burn out with the excessive amount of power and current.

Some specifications:

- The maximum power the subwoofers will accept is 600 W, (2 SKAR 8" subwoofers). I'll probably get a 500 W amp as well.
- I have 2x LED rings that require 12 V and 0.21 A, meaning they required a total of 5.04 watts.

What is the best way to go about this to convert to the proper amperage and watts?

The end goal is to make sure these LEDs don't burn out being triggered on and off for an excessive amount of time.

Comment: this sounds like you want to hook up a DC device (LEDs) to an AC source. That in itself isn't a great idea, so I'm almost sure you've got a more complex plan to start with that you don't describe? Also, it doesn't matter what your speaker chassis can take in power, what matters is how much voltage your amplifier will deliver in that case. All this seems not that great?

Comment: @MarcusMüller The whole idea of creating this speaker is to give it a party effect. I'm confused by your statement regarding "complex plan". What am I suppose to be describing?

Comment: well, hooking up a DC device to an AC source is not a great idea, so I thought there was more to your approach?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I thought car amps are DC sources?

Comment: No. How should their output be DC when it's an audio signal?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have an amazing plan and outline to piece together the speakers and everything. But I'm trying to create an efficient subwoofer box with LEDs that won't wear out overtime. I don't want to constantly replace the LED rings.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not to keen when it comes to electronics. I have a very minimal knowledge to currents. However, my knowledge of computers and coding are very high.

Comment: Start with peak voltage vs number of LEDs ON or current or brightness with LEd specs,  it will end up being logarithmic and there are some solutions for this, after you define these parameters, then specify attack and decay time LED voltage has a dynamic range of about 2dB in voltage and 30 dB in current but sound can be 30dB to 60dB range, so you can use Voltage to current ratio maybe to control ring. Specs?

Comment: Joshua, I'm confused. You say you have a plan how to connect everything, but you can't explain none of it? What *is* that plan?

Comment: There is an air of mystery around the plan.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The plan is to have proper current supply from the subwoofers to the LEDs.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 So there wouldn't be any converters I could by online? I would have to essentially create my own circuit?

Comment: Yes you'd have to make your own circuit for this--if you're looking for parts you can just buy, that makes this a product recommendation question, which is considered off-topic for this site and will be closed.

Comment: @Hearth Alright I just didn't know which direction to take. If you would mind transferring this topic over it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to move it to, and I don't have the authority to move questions anyway.

Comment: Joshua, we're moving forward (might not feel like it, but I promise we are): You say "proper current supply for LEDs from the subwoofer to the LEDs", but we don't know (at least I don't) what you mean with "proper". "Disco effect" sadly tells me nothing :( I think you'll find that once you've defined what you want to do in a little more detail, if possible as (mathematical) function of the signal you're sending to the subwoofer, it'll become easier to answer!

Comment: if you cannot define the peak voltage or current of woof er or LED's at various levels, then it is impossible to match

Comment: Are you planning to drive the LEDs using the AUDIO signal to the subwoofers?

Comment: @evildemonic yes Im trying to do exactly that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you would have a battery or auxillary power supply in the box that would drive the actual LEDs, and just sniff the audio level from the speakers. That would allow you to tailor audio thresholds and delay times to get whatever artistic effect you wanted. Drawing lighting power from the audio feed might cause distortion, depending on how stiff your amplifier output is.

However, as you say your skills are entirely in software, there is a cheap and cheerful way to do something that might suit your needs. If it doesn't, you still have the LEDs to do the job properly.

A 500 W amp, if rated into 8 ohms, will deliver about 63 V rms, or 88 V peak. If we assume your LED rings draw 200 mA at 12 V, then you'd want a series resistor of 380 ohms in series to limit the current to that. That's 15 W peak, but half that coming from an AC waveform, and a lot less than that due to the dynamics of music, so 5 W should be plenty.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIQmCB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Diodes D1 and D2 are necessary to protect your LEDs from the reverse voltage. Unfortunately you'll only have one or the other ring on instantaneously, but except for very low bass notes when they would appear to flicker, both rings will appear to be on when the note is loud enough.

This circuit will give some visible output any time the output is above 12 V, so there will need to be some decent output before they start to light.

If the 'loud note -> bright flash' that this would give is not the effect you want, then this won't do, and you will need a separate driver.

I notice you want to 'pulse with the bass'. Without C1, this circuit responds to all frequencies. However, bass notes tend to be louder than mid-range. If you did want to roll the response off above, let's say 400 Hz, then C1 would reduce the response. It would have to be rated to take the voltage, 100 V caps are easily obtainable.

Note that the main reason for this answer is to get you to try to describe what you want to do. I don't think this is a good way to flash LEDs, but it will work, and it's simple and cheap to make. Unlike incandescent lamps, LEDs can look pretty bright even when under-run, which is what this circuit has to do to avoid over-powering them on peaks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you play your very powerful audio system at full blast all the time?
If you make a very simple LED circuit that prevents the LEDs from burning out at full blast then the LEDs will be very dim at "normal" levels.

I have an LED VU meter with 10 LEDs in my family room. Its input is a microphone and it brightly shows 10 levels that are 3dB apart. When sound levels are very low then a Boost stage makes it 20dB more sensitive.